# Hide empty variation cutom fields displayed in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, metadata, product-variations

I'm using [Add variation setting fields to specific variable products in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77933178/add-variation-setting-fields-to-specific-variable-products-in-woocommerce/77933372#77933372) answer code, to show variation custom fields in WooCommerce, and It's working fine.

Now I would like to hide displayed variation custom fields data when empty. I tried to add this jQuery code:

```php
/* Hide empty custom fields for all variations */
function variation_custom_field_js() {
    
    foreach(  custom_fields_settings_all() as $field_key => $values ) {
            ?>
            <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                
                var CustomField = "<?php Print($field_key); ?>";
                //console.log(CustomField);

                $('.shop_attributes .<?php Print($field_key); ?>_class').hide();
    
                $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function(event, data) {

                    if ( data.<?php Print($field_key); ?> == '0' ) {

                        $('.shop_attributes .<?php Print($field_key); ?>_class').hide();
                    } else {

                        $('.shop_attributes .<?php Print($field_key); ?>_class').show();
                    }
                }).on('hide_variation', function(){

                    $('.shop_attributes .<?php Print($field_key); ?>_class').hide();
                });
            });
            </script>
            <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form', 'variation_custom_field_js' );
```

I can see the script on the frontend, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't provide the code that display the custom fields values on selected variations, is not possible to test anything…

Try the following replacement code (not really tested):

```php
/* Hide empty custom fields for all variations */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form', 'variation_custom_field_js' );
function variation_custom_field_js() {
    $field_keys = array_keys( custom_fields_settings_all() );
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery( function($){
        <?php foreach( $field_keys as $field_key ) { ?>
        $('.shop_attributes .<?php echo $field_key; ?>_class').hide();
        <?php } ?>

        $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function(event, data) {
            <?php foreach( $field_keys as $field_key ) { ?>
            console.log(data.<?php echo $field_key; ?>); // To be removed (testing)
            if ( data.<?php echo $field_key; ?> !== undefined ) {
                $('.shop_attributes .<?php echo $field_key; ?>_class').show();
            } else {
                $('.shop_attributes .<?php echo $field_key; ?>_class').hide();
            }
            <?php } ?>
        }).on('hide_variation', function(){
            <?php foreach( $field_keys as $field_key ) { ?>
            $('.shop_attributes .<?php echo $field_key; ?>_class').hide();
            <?php } ?>
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

It should work.

---

Here is a complete working example **that will display any non-empty custom field**, based on the selected variation:

```php
// Fields settings
function custom_fields_settings() {
    return array(
        'my_custom_field1' => array(
            'label'       => __('Text field Name 1', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder' => __('Text field placeholder 1', 'woocommerce'),
            'description' => __('Text field description 1', 'woocommerce'),
            'display'     => __('Name 1', 'woocommerce'),
        ),
        'my_custom_field2' => array(
            'label'       => __('Text field Name 2', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder' => __('Text field placeholder 2', 'woocommerce'),
            'description' => __('Text field description 2', 'woocommerce'),
            'display'     => __('Name 2', 'woocommerce'),
        ),
        'my_custom_field3' => array(
            'label'       => __('Text field Name 3', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder' => __('Text field placeholder 3', 'woocommerce'),
            'description' => __('Text field description 3', 'woocommerce'),
            'display'     => __('Name 3', 'woocommerce'),
        ),
    );
}


// Add custom field(s) to product variations from specific variable products
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'add_variation_setting_fields', 10, 3 );
function add_variation_setting_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    $targeted_ids = array(); // Targeted variable product Ids

    if ( $targeted_ids && ! in_array( $variation->post_parent, $targeted_ids ) ) return;

    foreach(  custom_fields_settings() as $field_key => $values ) {
        $args = array(
            'id'            => $field_key.'['.$loop.']',
            'wrapper_class' => 'form-row',
            'desc_tip'      => true,
            'value'         => get_post_meta($variation->ID, $field_key, true)
        );
        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array_merge( $args, $values) );
    }
}

// Save the custom field from product variations
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', 'save_variation_setting_fields', 10, 2 );
function save_variation_setting_fields($variation, $i) {
    foreach(  custom_fields_settings() as $field_key => $values ) {
        if ( isset($_POST[$field_key][$i]) ) {
            $variation->update_meta_data($field_key, sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field_key][$i]));
        }
    }
}

// Add variations custom fields to the variable product form data
add_action( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'add_variations_custom_fields_to_variable_product_form', 10, 3 );
function add_variations_custom_fields_to_variable_product_form( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $targeted_ids = array(); // Targeted variable product Ids

    if ( $targeted_ids && ! in_array( $product->get_id(), $targeted_ids ) ) return $data;

    foreach(  custom_fields_settings() as $field_key => $values ) {
        if ( $value = $variation->get_meta($field_key)) {
            $data[$field_key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return  $data;
}

// Output dynamically the HTML structure (where the custom fields will be displayed)
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'display_variation_custom_fields' );
function display_variation_custom_fields() {
    $html = '<div class="woocommerce-variation-cfs">';
    foreach( custom_fields_settings() as $field_key => $values ) {
        $html .= sprintf('<div class="%s" style="%s"><strong>%s:</strong> <span></span></div>',
        $field_key, 'display:none;', $values['display'] );
    }
    echo $html . '</div>';
}

// Show/hide custom fields, display the values based on the selected custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form', 'variation_custom_fields_js' );
function variation_custom_fields_js() {
    $field_keys = array_keys( custom_fields_settings() );
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function(event, data) {
            <?php foreach( $field_keys as $field_key ) { ?>
            const <?php echo $field_key; ?> = data.<?php echo $field_key; ?>;
            console.log(<?php echo $field_key; ?>); // To be removed (testing)
            if ( <?php echo $field_key; ?> !== undefined ) {
                $('.woocommerce-variation-cfs .<?php echo $field_key; ?> span').html(<?php echo $field_key; ?>);
                $('.woocommerce-variation-cfs .<?php echo $field_key; ?>').show();
            } else {
                $('.woocommerce-variation-cfs .<?php echo $field_key; ?>').hide();
                $('.woocommerce-variation-cfs .<?php echo $field_key; ?> span').html('');
            }
            <?php } ?>
        }).on('hide_variation', function(){
            <?php foreach( $field_keys as $field_key ) { ?>
            $('.woocommerce-variation-cfs .<?php echo $field_key; ?>').hide();
            $('.woocommerce-variation-cfs .<?php echo $field_key; ?> span').html('');
            <?php } ?>
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

Related: [Add variation setting fields to specific variable products in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77933178/add-variation-setting-fields-to-specific-variable-products-in-woocommerce/77933372#77933372)